# How to pick a file using F# Avalonia FuncUI, a problem with async

Tags: asynchronous, f#, avalonia

I've got a working FuncUI app, but adding a file picker to get some text from the file system is proving tricky. I've stripped my app down to the following app based on a modified version of the counter app on the Avalonia [FuncUI](https://github.com/fsprojects/Avalonia.FuncUI)  home page. It runs fine, but hangs at line 34 in the Async.RunSynchronously after you press the "Load File" button:

```
namespace CounterApp

open Avalonia
open Avalonia.Controls.ApplicationLifetimes
open Avalonia.Themes.Fluent
open Avalonia.FuncUI.Hosts
open Avalonia.Controls
open Avalonia.FuncUI
open Avalonia.FuncUI.DSL
open Avalonia.Layout
open Avalonia.Platform.Storage
open System.IO


module Main =

    let view () =
        Component(fun ctx ->
            let state = ctx.useState 0

            let top = TopLevel.GetTopLevel ctx.control

            let useFiles() =
              async {
                let options = FilePickerOpenOptions(Title = "Open Text File", AllowMultiple = false)
         
                let! result = top.StorageProvider.OpenFilePickerAsync(options) |> Async.AwaitTask
          
                return result
              }
            
            let callback _ =
              useFiles()
              |> Async.RunSynchronously |> ignore

            DockPanel.create [
                DockPanel.children [
                    Button.create [
                        Button.dock Dock.Bottom
                        Button.onClick callback
                        Button.content "Load file"
                        Button.horizontalAlignment HorizontalAlignment.Stretch
                        Button.horizontalContentAlignment HorizontalAlignment.Center
                    ]                   
                ]
            ]
        )

type MainWindow() =
    inherit HostWindow()
    do
        base.Title <- "Counter Example"
        base.Content <- Main.view ()

type App() =
    inherit Application()

    override this.Initialize() =
        this.Styles.Add (FluentTheme())
        this.RequestedThemeVariant <- Styling.ThemeVariant.Dark

    override this.OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted() =
        match this.ApplicationLifetime with
        | :? IClassicDesktopStyleApplicationLifetime as desktopLifetime ->
            desktopLifetime.MainWindow <- MainWindow()
        | _ -> ()

module Program =

    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main(args: string[]) =
        AppBuilder
            .Configure<App>()
            .UsePlatformDetect()
            .UseSkia()
            .StartWithClassicDesktopLifetime(args)
```

This is my best approximation at what might be a way to go, but I am now stuck. Any ideas on what would make this working code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While looking to see if anyone had answered my question, Google reported an Avalonia FuncUI link on [github](https://github.com/fsprojects/Avalonia.FuncUI/issues/132) to me, which in turn, led me to reading an article on [Elmish](https://zaid-ajaj.github.io/the-elmish-book/#/chapters/commands/), the wider context for my app.

Turns out all I needed to proceed was to make the callback a void function, and to start the task immediately:

```
let useFiles() =
  async {
    let options = FilePickerOpenOptions(Title = "Open Text File",
                                        AllowMultiple = false)
         
    let! result = 
      top.StorageProvider.OpenFilePickerAsync(options)
      |> Async.AwaitTask
                
    System.Console.WriteLine "result now available"
  }
            
let callback _ =
  useFiles()
  |> Async.StartImmediate
```

This successfully calls the file picker, thus solving my stated problem. I can now continue and make use of the file picker's choice returned in `result`.